# Stereographic Projection Mapping of Points on Z-plane

Tags: complex-analysis

In a stereographic projection why is that points on the z-plane inside the sphere mapped from southern hemisphere and points on the z-plane outside the sphere mapped from the northern hemisphere?

Note: The question was edited.

Comment: The line along which we project always starts at the same pole, conventionally the north pole. Where did you see it done differently?

Comment: I was watching a video on complex analysis...I begining to learn complex analysis....So the instructor made the claim that all points on the z-plane outisde the are mapped from north pole...and said it was directly evident that all points within the sphere are mapped from south pole...I couldn't get to the reasoning behind it

Comment: Are you sure they didn't talk about the northern and southern hemisphere instead of north and south pole?

Comment: yeah....I made a mistake there....it is hemisphere and not poles...do I edit the question?

Comment: Yes, then you should edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this picture demonstrating the stereographic projection:

[image]

If the ray starting at the north pole intersects the northern hemisphere (pictured: the ray through $A$), it leaves the sphere before intersecting the complex plane. Therefore, it can only intersect the complex plane outside the sphere.

Conversely, if the ray intersects the southern hemisphere (pictured: the ray through $B$), it must first intersect the plane to do so, and the ray only leaves the sphere afterwards. Therefore, it intersects the complex plane inside the sphere.

Comment: It makes sense now...thanks a lot @Vercassivelaunos